# Функция транслитерации русского в английский по правилам Яндекса на php

Tags: php

Может кто то встречал готовые решения например на `php` подобные функции?

Нашел на просторах `github` такой отрывок кода, с попыткой реализации по схеме с этих двух сервисов. [1](http://translit-online.ru/yandex.html) и [2](https://www.seo-ap.ru/translit/)

Но он далек от "правильности" работы.
Например в нем не учитывается правило что после букв `k` и `z`, буква `х` должна транслироваться в `hk`.
Например слово `эхо` транслируется этим кодом в `ehho`, тогда как должно быть `ehkho`.

Кроме того если попытаться добавить в паттерн `'/(c|s|e|h)h/i'` k и z `'/(k|z|c|s|e|h)h/i'` то `while (preg_match($pattern, $keyword)){}` уйдет в бесконечный цикл из за бесконечной попытки заменить `kh` на `kh`

```
    // Транслитерация по правилам яндекса
    $cyr = array(
        'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п',
        'р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',
        'ch','sh'
    );
    $lat = array(
        'a','b','v','g','d','e','yo','zh','z','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p',
        'r','s','t','u','f','h','c','c+h','s+h','s+hc+h','','y','','eh','yu','ya',
        'c+h','s+h'
    );
    $keyword = str_replace($cyr, $lat, $keyword);
    $pattern = '/(c|s|e|h)h/i';
    $replacement = '$1kh';
    while (preg_match($pattern, $keyword)) {
        $keyword = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $keyword);
    }
    $pattern = '/(c|s)\+h/i';
    $replacement = '$1h';
    while (preg_match($pattern, $keyword)) {
        $keyword = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $keyword);
    }
```

> P.S. Интересует функция работающая по правилам транслита от Яндекса.

Comment: А что за правила у Яндекса? Что касается транслита, дак вроде есть в Сети множество вариантов, работающих по одному и тому же  принципу: русские буквы - в массиве А; их эквиваленты - в массиве Б; поиск с заменой осуществляется например с помощью str_replace(А, Б, Строка).

Comment: Работая с ЧПУ не один год, я естественно применял разные варианты транслита, но они все далеко не идеальны с точки зрения сео и правильности по версии яндекса. ГОСТ как минимум там не катит. Например тут вот есть вариант в котором при определенных расстановках букв в слове после транслита, разные буквы трактуются по разному. http://translit-online.ru/yandex.html

Comment: Так же например есть правило где рядом стоящие несколько подряд заглавных букв, трактуются как аббревиатура и тоже обрабатываются по отдельной схеме.

Comment: Вот уже что то интересное попалось. https://github.com/kitcms/old/commit/5c9a98d60cec6172d1a0003f49387256029f124c#diff-1719e6488ec2ad667bfa61cecaf88816

Comment: Где документ Яндекса, описывающий его правила? Мало ли кто какой код нарисует.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Если бы так просто было бы найти документ, он уже был бы тут. Дополнительно вот еще более подробное описание того же механизма. https://www.seo-ap.ru/translit/

Comment: @KAGGDesign Есть четкие рекомендации от преподавателя из достаточно солидного вуза под названием "Специалист" на курсах по SEO, где все нюансы этого вопроса изучены за последние 10 лет. И вот они гласят четко никаких ГОСТ'тов при транслите урлов и никаких ISO, а только формат Яндекса который всем известен, но про документ ничего не сказано. Не удивительно что документа нету. Для вас может и удивительно если вы не сталкивались с SEO

Comment: Типичный SEO-байки ))) Документа нет, как работает Яндекс, неизвестно, но все точно знают, как под него оптимизировать сайты )) Удачи )

Comment: По сути вопроса - написать функцию транлита длео 5 минут. Можете взять примеры из плагинов транслитерации, заменив таблицы на свои.